# Can i render two different controller actions in a single page in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, controller

[image]

So basically what I am about to do is have a fixed search bar with is results.
And also **view page of the selected result with links to all its CRUD actions, and also link to move to other associated controllers.**

Now when I click on edit action or if I choose to move to another associated controller view the search bar and its results should be unchanged.
I have a basic understanding of jquery and ajax, would I need to try angular.js for this.

> So to summarize I need a fixed search bar with search results
>   unaffected on moving from one controller to other.

Please help me figure this out. If you have trouble understanding the question leave a comment.

Comment: So to speak similar to the working of frames in html. How do i implement this in rails. Think this as i SPA with a lots of functionalities.

Comment: don't know your experience in rails, this kind of stuff is super basic. Look into layouts (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), how things are to be organised, how variables ared passed from controller to views; you propably want to look into partials too. Once you get an idea of those mentionned aspects, it'll become obvious to you

Comment: The simple answer to "Can i render two different controller actions in a single page in rails?" is NO. Rails will call one controller action per request. Each action renders one view. However what you want can most like be achieved with view partials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render two (or more) variables in a controller you may do something wrong.

I see several options here.

1. You probably should have a page, when you already have a static bar but have nothing under it though. In that case, you simply call a controller for this bar and nothing more. Then you use ajax to render what's inside second 'frame'.
2. You probably will want to take a look at [Facade pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). It allows you to instantiate only one variable in a controller at a time. Also, it may somehow structurize things in your head, and you will see more pleasant ways.

(Also read [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers). It has a slight example of Facade with Rails)

Comment: Thank you, i needed a reference like this. I had no idea what they call these stuff.